# Any reason not to use a trusted friend known to my family as a will/estate executor?

Tags: estate-planning, will

I am not married and have no children, which means the handling of my personal property and finances in the tragic event of my death is less cut and dry than if either of those existed.

I am putting together a living will to handle end of life care, and items like that, but, I find that what I would prefer to do with my finances might need to be a bit taylored to the exact situation at the time of such a tragic demise.

As such, I am considering using an executor to handle certain aspects on the financial and personal property side.

So my questions are:

*Is there any reason I should not consider a long time personal friend of similar age that my family knows quite well, and whom I consider to be a fair and financially responsible individual, as an executor of my will/estate?*

*Should I name his wife, whom I also trust, as a co-excutor (executris?), or just leave him as the only one?*

For obvious reasons, I do not plan on naming them in my will in such a way as they have financial gain from the executor process.

Also, we're not talking enormous money here.  At this point in my life, total estate value counting life insurance would be less than $500,000 US.

Comment: For some reason, not displaying correctly.  Total estate value is less than $500,000 US.

Comment: The less-than symbol was treated as the opening tag of HTML, so the parser discarded what followed when it rendered it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Who you name as executor of your estate is to your judgment.  If you feel that this friend will execute your wishes, then that's really all that matters.

If your friend is your first choice, then name his wife as a back-up (in case something happens to him in the meantime).

You can change your executor as long as you're fit to do so, so this isn't a forever decision if you have a falling-out.